# Windows bootable install media hangs with faulty drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, repair

So, this laptop does not have a battery and the power was cut accidentally, when it was turned on again it just could not boot, I tried to mount the filesystem in read-only mode using a linux live USB but it failed, saying that it's inconsistent and it needed to be CHKDSK-ed.

And here I am, trying to run CHKDSK using the Windows 7 install media (from a USB HDD) to repair an inconsistent NTFS partition on a physically good mechanical HDD on a laptop, but the boot media hangs on a black screen after the "Loading files" progress bar.

I can see that the I/O led on the laptop is continuously lit, and I hear the disk is being read.

But then after 5 minutes or so it stops, the led is no longer lit and the disk does not spin anymore, but the screen would remain blank and will not advance anymore.

I presume that the install media is looking for an existing installation but since the filesystem is bad it is having trouble reading it, the problem is that I can't even fix it because it hangs before showing the repair options.

I have already read other answers but they all suggest using the installation media or even attaching the drive to another PC (which is not an option for me).

Are there any bootable alternatives to the Windows installation media to run CHKDSK? Thank you.

Also, I can tell that the HDD itself and other hardware is good because (using the Linux Live USB) I dd-ed the whole disk to null without any read errors, so the problem is (presumably) just the filesystem; also, the SMART self test reports only a very few reallocated sectors (13) and the read error rate is low.